# Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document' with Google Maps (InfoWindow issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to display [Tide Times](https://www.tidetimes.org.uk/widgets) in an infowindow on my Google Map.

Here's my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nvwjnrhy/1/.

My log reads: `Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.`.

*Is there a way to resolve this?*

---

Here's my current full code:

```js
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var marker;
var infoWindow;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);
  setLocation();
}

function setLocation() {
  var address = '2349 Marlton Pike W, Cherry Hill, NJ 08002';
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var position = results[0].geometry.location;
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: position,
        title: 'Venue Name'
      });
      map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

      
      var content = document.createElement('div');
      
      var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = "https://www.tidetimes.org.uk/grimsby-tide-times.js";
   content.appendChild(script);

      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: content
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });

      //infoWindow.open(map, marker); doesn't work
      google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click'); //still doesn't work
    } else {
      //
    }
  });
}

initialize();
//google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#map-canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Thank you for any help with this :)

Comment: I think InfoWindow doesn't support this. You should check out [InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html)

Comment: Oooooh thank you. Is this easy enough to implement? I'm quite new to JS

Comment: I don't know about tide times, but, come on... it has to be easy :D

Comment: Have you seen how tidetimes script works with the document.write?

Comment: As the log says, you can't use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) in an asynchronously executed function. `dW` is purposed to be used at parsing time or to create new documents, not to manipulate DOM.

Comment: Hi Teemu - is there a work around?  :)

Comment: No work-arounds, use proper DOM manipulation methods instead.

Comment: Teemu - can you show me how to do this?

Comment: @Teemu - Could I use `postscribe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing the content directly to the document you can concatenate the same and save it in a variable like for example ... (using https://www.tidetimes.org.uk/berkeley-tide-times.js)

```
var infoBoxContent = "";
infoBoxContent += '<div style="overflow:hidden; width:'+css.width+'; height:'+css.height+'; background:'+css.background+'; border:'+css.border+'; border-radius:'+css.corner+';">';
infoBoxContent += '<h2 style="text-align:center; margin:0px; color:'+css.color+'; padding:10px 0px 0px 0px; font:bold 14px sans-serif;"><a style="color:'+css.color+'" href="https://www.tidetimes.org.uk/berkeley-tide-times" title="Berkeley Tide Times">Berkeley Tide Times</a></h2>';
```

and so on...

**NOTE:** You need to save the script js file locally and edit it to be able to use it in this way.

once that string is built you can directly create an InfoWindow and assign the content to it.

```
var myOptions = {
     content: infoBoxContent,
     ...
};

var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
ib.open(theMap, marker);
```